# Android Things Rasperry PI GPS and Bluetooth Error

Tags: bluetooth, gps, android-things

I am getting an error once I load my app in Android Things on Rasperry PI, it shows a message about "Bluetooth has stopped".
This happens just after registering the GPS Driver. it does not affect the functionality and it is only at the first time.
It has already some permissions in the xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_GNSS_DRIVERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
```

Looks like it requires to switch the port to GPS or unregister Bluetooth first... By the way I am not using bluetooth feature in the app. any idea?
thanks

```
if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No permission");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Register the GPS driver
            mGpsDriver = new NmeaGpsDriver(context, "UART0", UART_BAUD, ACCURACY);
            mGpsDriver.register();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of the Raspberry Pi, as per [the pinout documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi#io-pinout):

> The Raspberry Pi has pins that are multiplexed between various board functions. Some board functions cannot be used simultaneously (for example, enabling Bluetooth and using the UART0 port for peripheral I/O).

So there may be a process running in the background which is still using Bluetooth and causing the driver to crash.